# Can't import dump from mapped net drive using data pump

Tags: oracle, import, network-drive, datapump, impdp

I'm trying to import few users from .dmp file from a net drive. Unofrtunately it seems that I lack some rights to do so since I get

```
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-31640: unable to open dump file "\\net\drive\directory\placeholder\my_dump.dmp" for read
ORA-27041: unable to open file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 5) Access is denied.
```

I'm not sure why, because I can both access that directory, and for example save a txt file there.

Directory is saved on database as '\net\drive\directory\placeholder'. Log file has other directory specified (not on net drive).

Is there any workaround to import this dump without actually moving it to local drive? Dump is really big, and I don't have space for it (not even close) and neither can I (probably) change my rights on this mapped drive.

Also I can't really make dump smaller.

On one site I've found this advice - " Remember, your OS user ID may not be the ID that is running a submitted RMAN job, in an operating system, UNIX, Linux or Windows."
The solution was to "

```
In the ControlPanel services:  
Right click on service
Select ?properties?
Select ?logon?
Change the default user ID to an Oracle user with Windows administrator privileges"
```

But I'm not sure what changing this would actually do to server/database, and I'm working on client's server so I don't want to act rashly. I also don't want to reset database or server itself.

Any help with what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your Oracle instance is running under different user account which doesn't have an access to the network drive.
Unless you don't want to run Oracle under different account, you can give the read access to the current Oracle's instance user account (usually LocalSystem for Windows platform) to your network share. Another option could be to import data from the source database via dblink (you won't need dump file in this case at all)

Comment: Figured it's something like that with read permissions, but sadly at that time I couldn't contact server's admin.
Regarding dblink - I totally didn't think about this solution. It would have been so much simpler.
In the end, I've just divided my environment to 5-6 separate dumps and was importing them one by one (load dump, import, delete dump, load new one, import...).
Still unless client enlrages server, dblink will be my best way to do that in the near future. Thanks for your help! Can't believe I haven't thought about it ;]